# $facet is not deserializing

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to run this command:

```
var applicationsPipeline = PipelineDefinition<AffiliateRecord, List<ApplicationRecord>>.Create(new IPipelineStageDefinition[] {
    PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match<AffiliateRecord>(filter),
    PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Unwind<AffiliateRecord, AffiliateRecord>("Applications"),
    PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match<AffiliateRecord>(matchApplications),
    PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.ReplaceRoot<AffiliateRecord, List<ApplicationRecord>>(x => x.Applications),
    PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Skip<List<ApplicationRecord>>(offset),
    PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Limit<List<ApplicationRecord>>(limit),
});

var applicationsFacet = AggregateFacet.Create("applications", applicationsPipeline);

var aggregate = collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Facet(applicationsFacet, ...);

var facetResult = await aggregate.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
System.FormatException: Cannot deserialize a 'List<ApplicationRecord>' from BsonType 'Document'.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work like this:

```
var applicationsPipeline = PipelineDefinition<AffiliateRecord, ApplicationRecord>.Create(new IPipelineStageDefinition[] {
       PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match<AffiliateRecord>(filter),
       PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Unwind<AffiliateRecord>(x => x.Applications),
       PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("$and", and)),
       PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.ReplaceRoot<BsonDocument, ApplicationRecord>("$Applications"),
       PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Skip<ApplicationRecord>(offset),
       PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Limit<ApplicationRecord>(limit)
 });
```

which makes me think that ReplaceRoot has some kind of bug because it forces me to set Toutput as List instead of ApplicationRecord.